# Is my lens good for a tiger safari?

Tags: lens, nikon, safari

I have Nikon D5200 and Tamron SP AF 70-300mm F/4-5.6 Di VC. Is this lens good enough to cover shots?

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based: "good enough" depends on what you're wanting to do with it.

Comment: The question is incomplete, lacks all effort of providing information and the answer is (hence) completely opinion-based. vote to close.

Comment: Acting on above information, do not forget there are good companies out there, who rent good lenses at a very reasonable cost + Insurance.
You might want to try some of them, and see what is on offer.
Good Luck

Comment: Fast lens. Long focal length. Inexpensive. Pick any two, but you can't have all three.

Comment: A friend of mine went to Namibia with this very lens and took some sweet pictures of lions if I correctly recall. Anyway if you're not sure about it, consider renting a lens directly there

Answer (score 3):

The lens and camera are probably "good enough", but they're ( of course ) not ideal.  Unless you've a very large budget they're as good as you'll get.  An ideal system would be much larger ( heavier and costlier ) and be more complex to use ( which is itself a handicap ! ).  Better the equipment you know than something you don't.

Given that wildlife shots are difficult to take, the problem is never just the camera and lens, it's the user.  At the risk of being insulting, which is not the intent, if you have to ask about the lens, then you're probably lacking the experience to do better with a better lens anyway.  Good wildlife shots simply require practice and experience, no different from any other shooting scenario.

If you want to improve your keeper rate on the safari, go and practice wildlife or people shots in difficult lighting.  Evening and early morning when the light is relatively poor.  Get as good as you can at focusing manually and with your AF system in these conditions.  The better you get, the better shots you will take.

So I would concentrate on practice and getting to know your equipment rather than worrying about new equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't really understand what he wants to do either but Philip Kendall has a point saying :

> The answers will be completely different for "show a few photos on my phone >to my family" and "get published in National Geographic"

So Ill answer your question and give you my thoughts if it was me .

A safari like that is most likely pretty expensive so I wouldn not wanna end up with crappy pictures (If i decide to take pictures at all - For a while now I enjoy the views and the travels rather then try to capture them .). So its wildlife and its a dangerous animal so u wanna stay as far away as possible (and most likely your guides will keep you at a safe distance too). A telephoto lens is what I will take and I will make sure its the fastest one I can get f2.8 or af f4 . Now considering their costs most likely I'll rent it andbest option will be to rent it there not to carry a 500f4 on a plane . Also I will take a fast body Nikon D810 maybe but is a Full frame so no extra points for cropping and making your lens of choice even longer . D7200 is another choice DX sensor(croping ! ) 6 fps . I will shoot and not check if I am you . Jpgs  maximum speed as many as I can . Don't look at the screen most likely it wont help anyway . Set the camera to shutter Mode and control the apperture . The new 200–500mm f/5.6 is a good choice as well Its big but not huge an long and zoomable . Also I will get an ultrazoom with me maybe NIKKOR 18-300mm f/3.5-6.3G ED VR and mount it on my existing body in your case the 5200 . In fact I would say I would try to capture the tigers but also the nature around them so the 18 or 50 or 100 mm might will be very usefull. Be ready to sacrifice quality and crank that ISO but get sharp pictrures . Belive me you can fix a lot in PS but a blurred tiger u can't :).

So with fewer words - Get a niuce fast body and a good fast telephoto lens there - Rent them use them hard return them . Use your camera as a backup and another type of shots ( Dont try to capture the same with both ). Get plenty of cards and charged batteries !!! . 
Lastly dont spend the whole thing behind a camera - enjoy it .

Answer (score -2):

Don't have enough reputation to comment but I totally disagree with Philip. He told us what he wants to do with it.

Though to be fair the answer is still subjective. I say absolutely not, 450mm (300mm plus the crop factor since it's an APS-C sensor) will not get you far enough away from tigers. Nikon just released a very affordable 200-500/5.6 which is getting very positive reviews and may be worth consideration. Or, if you're rich, a 400/2.8 or 500/4 will give you far more resolution and AF speed.

Comment: No, he didn't say what he wants to do with it. The answers will be *completely* different for "show a few photos on my phone to my family" and "get published in National Geographic".

Comment: He's not asking what he wants to do with the lens, but with the pictures. Are you going to SHOW them on your phone, or print 24-36 prints and try to sell them?

Comment: Ah you're right I misread. I deleted that comment. However, I do stand by the fact that regardless of whether or not you need the image quality a very long telephoto offers, you still need one to allow you to be a safe distance from the tigers.